# Google Maps API Toggle draggable true / false

Tags: jquery, function, google-maps, toggle, draggable

I'm trying to create a button that when clicked, toggles the value (true/false) of google maps jquery function 'draggable'.

I've been searching and got as far as finding this code which looks like it could be what I'm after:

```
var x = false;
$(element).on('click', function(){
 if (!x){
  //function
  x = true;
 }
 else {
  //function
  x = false;
 }
});
```

But I'm stuck as to how to implement it, or if it's even the right path to go down.

Here's my maps jquery:

```
 function initialize() {

   var styles = [ { },{ } ];


    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
      {name: "Styled Map"});

    var locations = [
  ['WELWYN GARDEN CITY&nbsp;', 51.805616,-0.192647, 2],
  ['STANMORE &nbsp;', 51.603199,-0.296803, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
navigationControl: true,
scrollwheel: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  draggable: false,
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.75339,-0.210114), 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var image = '/images/icons/map.png';

var marker, i;


 for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2], locations[i][3], locations[i][4], locations[i][5], locations[i][6], locations[i][7], locations[i][8], locations[i][9], locations[i][10], locations[i][11], locations[i][12], locations[i][13], locations[i][14], locations[i][15], locations[i][16], locations[i][17], locations[i][18], locations[i][19]), 
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    zIndex: 10
  }); 





  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
 map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
  }
```

Hope this makes sense, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. make your map global.
2. toggle it's draggable property like this:

   function toggleMapDraggable() {
       if (map.get("draggable")) {
           map.set("draggable",false);
       } else {
           map.set("draggable",true);
       }
   }

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function toggleMapDraggable() {
  if (map.get("draggable")) {
    map.set("draggable", false);
  } else {
    map.set("draggable", true);
  }
}

function initialize() {

  var locations = [
    ['WELWYN GARDEN CITY&nbsp;', 51.805616, -0.192647, 2],
    ['STANMORE &nbsp;', 51.603199, -0.296803, 1]
  ];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    navigationControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.75339, -0.210114),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';

  var marker, i;


  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      zIndex: 10
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" value="toggle draggable" onclick="toggleMapDraggable();" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```